# Ways to test the accuracy of recurrent neural network

Tags: testing, recurrent-neural-network

I'm doing research about recurrent neural networking.

I'm stumped how to test its accuracy.

The `rnn` measures the measures the given text into its category.

Please give me ways to test it. The more ways, the better.

Comment: Ways to test what? You didn't mention any libraries or give any specifics about what you're asking for. "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." ([What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that when you train these networks you should reserve part of your training data for a testing phase.

That way you have some labeled data that you can use to evaluate the accuracy of your model.